# Why keras theano backend outperforms tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, theano

I just dove into my first deep-learning project to get familiar with keras and tf.
It is a multi-label classification problem where I'm using a simple convolutional network to identify individual chemical compounds from XRD-patterns.

It took me some time but the results really blew my mind. I did not expect my simple network to perform that good in terms of accuracy.

Then I realized that I've been using theano as backend.
So I gave it another try with tensorflow and the very same input data gave terrible results. Even worse than a random forest classifier.

I'm pretty much clueless what is going on there.
I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I just couldn't figure out what ....

Anyway, here's the code (the input data is provided below...)

Theano_vs_TF.py:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='theano'

from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras as K

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

X=np.loadtxt('X.txt')
Y=np.loadtxt('Y.txt')

X3d = np.expand_dims(X, axis=-1)

# start with TF-model
tf_model = keras.Sequential()
wreg = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0) # dont use for now

tf_model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 8,strides=8, padding='same',
                        input_shape=(180,1), activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))

tf_model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 5,strides=5, padding='same', 
                        activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))

tf_model.add(layers.Conv1D(16, 3,strides=3, padding='same', 
                        activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))

tf_model.add(layers.Flatten())
tf_model.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))
tf_model.add(layers.Dense(29, activation='sigmoid',kernel_regularizer=wreg))

tf_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

tf_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf_optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              )

tf_model.summary()

# train tf-model
tf_history = tf_model.fit(X3d,Y,batch_size=128, 
                    epochs=50, verbose=1,validation_split=0.3,
                   )

plt.plot(tf_history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(tf_history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# now compare to theano model
th_model = Sequential() #old way
wreg = K.regularizers.l2(l=0.0) # 1e-3 was way too much, no hints for overfitting so far

th_model.add(K.layers.Conv1D(32, 8,strides=8, padding='same',
                          input_shape=(180,1), activation='relu', 
                          kernel_regularizer=wreg))

th_model.add(K.layers.Conv1D(32, 5,strides=5, 
                          padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))

th_model.add(K.layers.Conv1D(16, 3,strides=3, padding='same', activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))
th_model.add(K.layers.Flatten())
th_model.add(K.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=wreg))
th_model.add(K.layers.Dense(29, activation='sigmoid'))


#Define optimizer        
optimizer = K.optimizers.adam(lr=1e-3)

# Compile model
th_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'],

              )

th_model.summary()

# train th model and plot metrics
th_history = th_model.fit(X3d,Y,batch_size=128, 
                    epochs=50, verbose=1,validation_split=0.3,
                   )

plt.plot(th_history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(th_history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Uguu links (will expire after 24h)
[X.tar.gz](https://a.uguu.se/wnqryp.tar.gz)
[Y.tar.gz](https://a.uguu.se/usjmgj.tar.gz)

Tensorflow learning curve:
[image: Learning curve with tf backend]

Theano learning curve:
[image: Learning curve with theano backend]

Comment: That is quite strange. You could try explicitly specifying the initialization scheme for the layer parameters, although I think Keras should use the same default for all. Are the results repeatable? You can try fixing the random seed for Theano and TensorFlow, and trying different seeds, see if the difference is consistent.

Comment: I just gave it a try with different seeds for the glorot initializier in both tf and theano. Of course there's some variance, but still, the tf-performance remains way below theano